# Netlogo - non-valid results from random float, logic, and choosers

Tags: netlogo

In Netlogo, I use choosers to pick a strategy and its associated outcome given an event. In my case, building codes are the strategy, fire damage is the outcome, and a fire is the event). A random variable denotes whether a fire event occurs. However, my results are not valid (I sometimes get fire damage > 0 resulting from a p > 0.40). Thank you so much for any insight regarding the problem.

```
to fire? 

ask patches [

if (strategy = "updated-building-codes")

    [set p random-float 1.00

    if p > 0.40 [ set fire-level 0 ] 
    if p > 0.01 and p <= 0.40 [ set fire-level 1 ]
    if p > 0.002 and p <= 0.01 [ set fire-level 2 ]
    if p <= 0.002 [ set fire-level 3 ]
    ]

if (strategy = "no-updated-building-codes")

    [set p random-float 1.00

    if p > 0.40 [ set fire-level 0 ] 
    if p > 0.01 and p <= 0.40 [ set fire-level 5 ]
    if p > 0.002 and p <= 0.01 [ set fire-level 6 ]
    if p <= 0.002 [ set fire-level 7 ]
    ]    
]
end
```

Comment: James, can you add more detail? It may be hard to replicate your error with just what is shown here. Check out the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and specifically the part on [minimal code examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From what I can see, the logic of your posted code looks fine, but out of curiosity, how are you monitoring "p" for each individual patch? That is to say, how are you checking which "p" values led to fires?

Comment: Sorry for the minimalism, I'll work on that. "p" is a global variable, which I must have been forcing it into a patch context. Thank you, I think you really helped me fix the problem!!!

Comment: No worries, it just increases the chance that your question will be answered! Glad you sorted it out.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code you've shown. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else?